# PHP MYSQL Output Uniform Value to same Table Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in my MySQL like the below

```
============================
id  | courses   | r_number  
----------------------------
1   | English   | C/009
2   | Maths     | C/009
3   | English   | C/003
4   | Maths     | C/002
============================
```

How do I ouput this to be like the HTML table below

```
====================================
id  | courses           | r_number  
------------------------------------
1   | English, Maths    | C/009
2   | English           | C/003
3   | Maths             | C/002
====================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  MIN(ID) ID,
        GROUP_CONCAT(Courses SEPARATOR ', ') Courses,
        r_Number
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY r_Number
ORDER   BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2cec/2)

*I'm wondering why in your example the `ID` doesn't match with the record, why is that?*

Comment: The second table is the out on a HTML table. Thanks for the boost. I'm back on track!